# Как создать объект с помощью метода?

Tags: javascript

Как создать объект с помощью метода `Collection.from()` конструктора `Collection`?

Спасибо за ответы.

```
function Collection() {}

var letters = Collection.from(['a', 'b', 'c']);

letters instanceof Collection; // true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать экземпляр `Collection` можно с помощью [оператора `new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

Поэтому в простейшем случае код будет таким:

```js
function Collection() {}

Collection.from = function() {
  return new Collection();
}

console.log(Collection.from([1, 2, 3]) instanceof Collection);
```

---

Однако, в этом случае переданный параметр игнорируется, так как никак не используется в конструкторе.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Collection() {
}


var letters = Collection.from([
{
    id: "1",
    username: "Naida",
    images: "images/basa_user/user1.jpg"
},
{
    id: "2",
    username: "Elijah",
    images: "images/basa_user/user2.jpg"
}
]);

letters instanceof Collection; 
*** Если правильно понял
```

Comment: просто выполни свой код, и посмотри что выведет `letters instanceof Collection`. Автор вопроса хочет, чтобы вывелось `true`

Answer (score 0):

Это?

```js
function Collection() {}

Collection.from = function(args){
  return new Collection(args);
}

var letters = Collection.from(['a', 'b', 'c']);

console.info(letters instanceof Collection); // true
```

Можно поинтересоваться зачем?

Answer (score 0):

```
function Collection() {
}

Collection.from = function (obj) {
  const copy = Object.assign({}, obj); // чтобы не изменять переданный объект
  Object.setPrototypeOf(copy, Collection.prototype)
  return copy;
}

var letters = Collection.from(['a', 'b', 'c']);

console.log(letters instanceof Collection); // true
```